# Is there any well known signature(hash) algorithm generating 8 bytes long output?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, web-scraping, decompiling

I want to scrape data via a mobile app interface, unfortunately there is a signature parameter.
I tried to decompile a andorid app, The frustrating thing is that the signature algorithm is not written by Java(So couldn't view the source), it's in a external library (a libencrypt.so file).

The encrypt fuction takes a array as input.

['',
'4314',
'PEK',
'PVG',
'2016-04-07',
'MU5183',
'1459997456991']

e.g. The above input will gemerate a hash result(the signature parameter): 'c7802d46'

Now i just want to touch my luck. 
Is there any well known signature(hash) algorithm generating 8 bytes long string as this?

Comment: The question is wrong. That is the hex representation of the value of an 32 bits integer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 32-bit integer (in hex) it is probably a [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).